# How to reach a specific value (integer) with different database entries?

Tags: php, mysql, combinations

This is my code so far, apart from the connection:

```
$query = $handler->query('SELECT imagepath FROM table LIMIT 5');

while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    extract($r, EXTR_SKIP);

    echo "<img src='{$imagepath}'>";
}
```

This was mainly for experimental purposes and now I got stuck. I have many rows in my table and each row has a specific imagepath & a specific value (integer). I now want to reach an integer of 3000 with 5 random or valuesize sorted elements, which then get loaded and the connected image (via imagepath) should be displayed. The '3000' can have a tolerance of +-50 to 100 and if no combination fits it should output a error-message.

Do you have an idea of how I can manage this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, this question is not clear. What do you expect to get at the end?

Comment: In the end I want to display 5 images via the imagepath, which is bound to my entries. In addition to that I already bound different values (integers) to each entry in the range of 100-1000. 

The code should output 5 elements with their value summed up to be 3000 (maybe I can add a tollerance in the future due tue complexity in the future, but for now it should be work like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the cuff, this is probably best achieved with two queries. In the first query, obtain a list of all image keys (ids) and their integer values. The application can use its specific logic to compute a result that satisfies your requirements (five random images whose total value meets some range). Finally, once you have the IDs/keys of the images, you can fetch just those image paths.

If you are having issues figuring out how to randomly choose five image to fill, this is sort of a one-dimensional [bin-packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). One possible solution to these is to use a  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm.